# How to add to a collection which is already stored in a collection?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have the following:

```
class SpritesheetManager{

        std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unordered_set<std::string>> _loadedFiles;

        void addFileToFileListForSheet(std::string sheetprefix,std::string filename);
}
```

When adding files I do this:

```
void SpritesheetManager::addFileToFileListForSheet(std::string sheetprefix,std::string filename){
    bool containsKey = (_loadedFiles.find(sheetprefix)!= _loadedFiles.end());

    std::unordered_set<std::string> values;
    if(!containsKey){
        _loadedFiles[sheetprefix] = values;
    }

    _loadedFiles[sheetprefix].insert(filename);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Pass your strings using const references. Use `count` instead of `find`. Don't construct an unordered_set unless you need to. Or just use operator[] as the answer below suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that `operator[]` automatically default constructs and inserts a value if you try to access a key that does not exist, you can simplify your code to this:

```
void SpritesheetManager::addFileToFileListForSheet(std::string sheetprefix,std::string filename) {
    _loadedFiles[sheetprefix].insert(filename);
}
```

Comment: does that mean when I use "find" for a specific key, that a value is created an inserted if the key doesn't exist ?

Comment: Only `operator[]` does it. It's kind of a peculiar behavior, but there's a reason why it doesn't come in a `const` version.

Answer (score 1):

Etienne de Martel's answer would simplify the code if you keep this data-structure.
However, if you don't need any functionality that's common to the sheet prefix (like going over all the files with the same prefix, etc), and just care about keeping multiple files with the same prefix, you could simplify your code considerably by using an `unordered_multimap`:

Header:

```
class SpritesheetManager {    
        std::unordered_multimap<std::string, std::string> _loadedFiles;

        void addFileToFileListForSheet(std::string sheetprefix, std::string filename);
}
```

Implementation:

```
void SpritesheetManager::addFileToFileListForSheet
    (std::string sheetprefix, std::string filename) {
    _loadedFiles.insert(std::make_par(sheetprefix, filename));
}
```